# Returning a const double pointer to const data

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, casting, constants

I have an `int** matrix` and I would like to return it, as read-only.

So, I would do:

```
int const ** const get_matrix() {
  return (int const ** const)matrix;
}
```

but now I tried to do it like this:

```
int const ** const get_matrix() {
    return static_cast<int const ** const>(matrix);
}
```

and got:

> invalid static_cast from type ‘int**’ to type ‘const int** const’

Why?

Comment: Const_cast doesn't work?  I'd try that first

Comment: Yes @rholmes, I didn't know of it! I marked it as a dupe. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
int const ** const get_matrix() {
    return const_cast<int const ** const>(matrix);
}
```

It's working.